# How to enable both HTTP and HTTPS in Tomcat without redirect?

Tags: tomcat

I am configuring Tomcat to support both HTTP (on port 8080) and HTTPS (port 8443). In the server.xml, if I configure like this:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
           redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           SSLEnabled="true"
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true"
           Server=""
           keystoreFile="conf/.keystore"
           keystorePass="password"
           maxThreads="150"
           maxSpareThreads="75"
           minSpareThreads="25" 
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           />
```

All access to http://SERVER_IP:8080 will be directed to https://SERVER_IP:8443. How can I disable the redirection, and allow both http and https access?

I tried to remove `redirectPort="8443"`, but it does not work.

Comment: This configuration is correct. Could you post the `security-constraint` element of your `web.xml` file. Remove `HTTPSOnly` if exists

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I remove `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` from web.xml file, and now I have both HTTP and HTTPS access!

Comment: <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee> worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

With @pedrofb 's help, I figured out the solution: besides modifying server.xml file, edit web.xml file like:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Support Both HTTP and HTTPS
    </web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <!-- <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> -->
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Make sure `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` is commented, or else it allows only HTTPS access.

Comment: <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee> also works.